# Laravel 500 |server error on shared hosting

Tags: laravel, installation, cpanel, shared-hosting

I'm trying to upload my Laravel project to my shared hosting cPanel its not my first time that I've uploaded the Laravel project but this time I think I'm out of luck I'm facing 500 server error.
[here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c96D2.png)

I already try all the solution even I turn on debug too but nothing seems to work.

what I did is upload public files into my subdomain folder and rest into an other folder outside of subdomain folder I also try `php_info();` and everything is enabled. could you please help me out.

Also nothing is in error log for this error.

Answer (score -1):

The way i deploy on shared hosting. I do have the files in the `public` folder in the root directory. while in the `index.php` i point it to the laravel folder.

Here is how the directory will look like, take for example my laravel project is called `willa`:

- willa
- favicon.ico
- .htaccess
- index.php

My `index.php` look like this:

```
<?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
 */

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| I removed the comments.
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

require __DIR__.'/willa/vendor/autoload.php';


$app = require_once __DIR__.'/willa/bootstrap/app.php';


$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

My `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thank you I've fixed the issue but now I'm getting into another problem symlink when i run {php artisan storage:link
} this command I got an error "symlink(): No such file or directory"

Comment: You just have to edit your `filesystem.php` to suit the new directory where your storage folder is located. In this case, storage folder is located in the root directory. All you have to do to the root of the driver is:
```
'root' => base_path('../storage'),
```